# How to use multiple versions of Julia on Windows

Tags: windows, julia, version

I have installed both Julia 1.5.2 as well as Julia 1.6.1

But my default Julia version is still 1.5.2 on command prompt. How can I change it or use both version on command prompt?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The command prompt reads from your PATH variables, which you can edit in the relevant settings. On Windows 10, if you just search for PATH you should be offered these options:

[image]

From there, click "Environment Variables", then select "Path" in the next window and press "Edit". You should see a list of your current environment variables which includes Julia 1.5.2 and 1.6.1 installation paths. You can now remove Julia 1.5.2 (or move 1.6.1 above 1.5.2 in the list) to make 1.6.1 the default version that gets started when you type `julia` at the prompt.

Note that you'll have to restart your terminal (or maybe even your system) for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit:

The simplest solution is now to install Julia through the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/julia/9njnww8pvkmn), this installs the Julia version manager [juliaup](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup)

updating and switch julia versions is so much easier with this:

set the default version:

```
juliaup default 1.5.3
```

add a specific version:

```
juliaup add 1.5.1
juliaup add beta
```

launch a specific version (must be `add`ed before)

```
julia +1.5
julia +beta
```

#### Old answer:

I use Powershell, here is what I do,

you can define aliases in `$profile`:

```
New-Alias julia1.6.1 C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia-1.6.1\\bin\\julia.exe
New-Alias julia1.5.3 C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia-1.5.3\\bin\\julia.exe
New-Alias julia julia1.6.1
```

to see where it is and edit it:

```
echo $profile
notepad $profile
```

then, you can call `julia`, `julia1.5.3` etc...

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite easy.

First of all, you have to find the folders in which both version are installed. By default that would be `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Julia-1.X.X`. In your case there should be `Julia-1.5.2` and `Julia-1.6.1`.

When you located them, you should check what your `Path` variable is. I can't tell for sure, but I suspect that your `Path` is pointing to both 1.5.2 and 1.6.1 versions, and because the executable files have the same name it just takes the first one. If it isn't, add a new value.

Now you can rename one of your executables. For example, rename file `Julia-1.5.2/bin/julia.exe` to `julia-5.exe`.